# Is it possible to color a specific item in a Tkinter combobox list? (in python)

Tags: python, tkinter, colors, combobox

here is my code:

---

```
import tkinter as tkp

from tkinter import ttk

from tkinter import messagebox

window = tkp.Tk()
window.geometry("600x500")

if __name__ == "__main__" :

    cities = ['OIII','OITT','OIHH','OISS','OIBB']
    txtCityName = ttk.Combobox(window, width = 13, height=15, values=cities, font='sans 10 bold')

    txtCityName.pack()
    window.mainloop()
```

---

I want to change the color of 'OIHH' and 'OISS' on the list box to red and the others to blue.
thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Your title mentions a listbox, but your code doesn't have a listbox in it.

Comment: txtCityName = ttk.Combobox(window, width = 13, height=15, values=cities, font='sans 10 bold') , cities is my list. if you run my code you will see the drop down list.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot change the color of an item in the dropdown list of a ttk Combobox.